# Delphi 32 bit app Can't find registry key that was written by 32 bit installer in Wow64 in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, registry, 32bit-64bit, firebird

While researching this problem I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8864595/71200) question. I'm having the exact same problem accept my program is already running as administrator and is already accessing the registry using `TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ)`.

The key I'm trying to access is `HKLM\Software\FireBird Project\Firebird Server\Instances`. The way I understand it (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that the registry redirector is enabled by default for any 32 bit process that reads or writes to HKLM\Software unless it is explicitly disabled.

Is there any way to tell if this the case with this key? I've looked through the source for the win32 firebird installer and nothing stuck out.

**Update**

!@#$%

Turned out it was finding the key all along. I was using this key to locate the isql utility so I could create a firebird database. This was happening in the `BeforeConnect` event of a db connection. For whatever reason the connection was being attempted and raising an exception before the event was triggered so the database was never getting created. Note to self: Never trust a Before* event to happen before anything.

Comment: If you look through the registry with regedit, is the key under `Software` or `Software\Wow6432Node`?

Comment: Huh. Try explicitly specifying `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard In this case the process will be a 32 bit process so the redirector will do the job.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would have thought so too, but I think the problem is that the key's not showing up from the 32bit process. Maybe Delphi is defaulting to `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` for some reason..

Comment: @Blorgbeard No, Delphi doesn't do that. The facts don't stack up.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864595/failed-to-read-win-registry-firebird-key-using-delphi

Comment: Similar except I'm already doing the recommended solution and the problem still exists.

Comment: Are you embedding a UAC manifest in your application?

Comment: @kobik asks that question because a manifest is what you need to avoid being virtualized.

Answer (score 2):

Most keys under `HKLM\Software` are subject to [redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx) and this key falls into that category. It will be redirected when accessed from a 32 bit process running under the WOW64 emulator.

Use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` to access the 32-bit view of the registry or `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to access the 64-bit view of the registry. Specify neither to access the view of the registry with the same bitness as the calling process.

The full list of keys that are affected by redirection is here: [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253.aspx).

The table presented there is a little tricky to read. For example, and considering only Windows 7, `HKLM\Software` is marked a being redirected. However, a number of sub keys are marked as being shared rather than redirected. Shared means that both 32 and 64 bit processes see the same underlying data. So, not all sub-keys of `HKLM\Software` are redirected. If a sub-key of `HKLM\Software` is not indicated as being shared, then it is redirected. And that's the case for your key.

---

In the question title and in the comments you indicate that the key you are looking for is in the 32 bit view of the registry. In that case, since your process is also 32 bit, you have nothing to do. Open the registry with `KEY_READ` only. You don't need to elevate to admin because you are only reading. You then ask to read `HKLM\Software\FireBird Project\Firebird Server\Instances` and let the redirector take you to the 32 bit view under `Wow6432Node`.

One of the golden rules of using the registry is that you should never hard-code `Wow6432Node` in your app. Let the redirector do the work.

Comment: The app is running as admin for other reasons. As I mentioned above I am already accessing the registry with read only permissions but for some reason it can't find the key. Is is possible registry virtualization is also playing a part it this?

Comment: Virtualization could be hurting you. Is your app running virtualized? I'd completely forgotten about that. Please please don't tell me you haven't moved on from running virtualized yet!

Comment: This app is about 20 years old. It writes configuration and data to the same folder as the executable (which is usually located one level beneath the root). It uses WinAPI functions that require administrative access. It modifies registry settings that don't belong to it. If we attempted windows logo certification it would take years to get it in shape.

Comment: you don't need to logo it, just add an app manifest